# Have compilation errors / grep match reuse current frame/window without ever splitting it?

Tags: frames, window-splitting, compilation, grep

I have searched in a number of places ([1](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2189/how-can-i-prevent-a-command-from-using-specific-windows), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813273/emacs-23-2-opens-a-new-window-for-each-compile-error-warning-navigated-to#), [3](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19080/is-there-a-better-way-to-override-opening-window-in-compilation-goto-locus), [4](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32775/compile-goto-error-be-more-consistent-in-choosing-a-window-for-display)) even looked at the e-lisp source files and could not figure out how to do, so I ask.

### Context

I have bound `next-error` to a key. I'm in some source code buffer and press the key. When walking to next error (compilation, grep, etc), emacs always makes sure to show the error buffer and the source code buffer.

### What emacs does

The problem is, it insists in showing them in the same frame, splitting the current frame.

## What I want

- Always show source code / grep match in *the window which happens to be selected* at the time `next-error` is run.

  - never split that window (customizing `split-*-threshold` is not enough)
  - if `next-error` brings to another source file, show it in current window, no split, no new frame (dedicated buffers don't seem to be enough).
- Regarding "compilation error"/"grep" buffer, if it is shown in any window, scroll to the appropriate line. Never split any window.

#### Accepted variants

Not to ask for more, but be more open to variations.
For example, existing emacs logic may make some variants actually easier to implement:

- Similar to what ediff does when switching to next difference, if a frame currently shows the compilation/grep buffer, then putting that frame on top is acceptable.
- If no frame currently shows the compilation/grep, it is acceptable either to not show it, or to open a new frame showing it.

### One possible implementation

- Just removing any attempt to split or make buffer visible would be acceptable.

**How to do that?**

Comment: Just found a [similar question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16456/how-can-i-force-emacs-to-never-split-frames-in-particular-for-compile-goto-erro?rq=1) and tried the suggested change. When advancing through grep results or compilation errors *on the same file* results it's great, but it causes emacs to *open a new frame whenever a buffer change is needed*, which is not what I want. I want the *currently focused window* to switch the next source file, yet still occupy the whole frame.

Comment: One workaround would be selecting the source code frame and do `M-: (set-frame-parameter nil 'unsplittable t)`. But that is attached to a particular frame, not change the general `next-error` behavior.

Comment: A hacky solution if there are not other windows in the same frame you are bothered with : bind your key to 

`(lambda() (next-error) (delete-other-windows))`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```el
(defun my-compile-goto-error-condition (_buffer _action)
  "`display-buffer-alist' condition callback."
  (member this-command '(next-error previous-error compile-goto-error)))

(defun my-display-buffer-full-frame (buffer _action)
  "`display-buffer' function."
  (let ((window (display-buffer-same-window buffer nil)))
    (delete-other-windows window)
    window))

(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist '(my-compile-goto-error-condition
                                     . (my-display-buffer-full-frame)))
```

Comment: IIUC, this says "whenever compilation/grep features used, also make current buffer fill-frame". This feels a little hackish yet is an interesting progress compared with the previous workaround `M-: (set-frame-parameter nil 'unsplittable t)` because it works in all frames.

Comment: There is a drawback, though. If I manually take care that the compilation/grep buffer match buffer (not source code buffer) is visible somewhere, I can see the small triangle advancing as I walk the matches, but the buffer would not scroll to maintain visibility of that triangle, a benefit that plain next-error does.

Comment: I'm not convinced my code actually does what I wanted it to, tbh.  I think it's mostly working by side-effect :)  I'm not going to follow it up right now, but it might give you other ideas to follow up on your own...